# Environments with multi-stages pipeline in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codepipeline

When we created project it deployed on Staging dev (refer to below used yaml template). Now whenever we commit it does so. Now our problem is we need dev and production environment with a manual approval stage from staging to prod.
We have added two stages as per below image (approval & prod)
[image]

Can someone help to say how can I modify my below YAML code to say :

if $CODEBUILD_BUILD_STAGE == 'prod'
target_bucket = $S3_BUCKET_PROD
ELSE
target_bucket = $S3_BUCKET_DEV

This is my code without approval & prod stages :

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    S3_BUCKET: "s3-frontend"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies
      - cd project
      # Install node dependancies.
      - npm install
      - npm install -g @angular/cli@"~9.1.1"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=16384
      #building 
      - ng build --aot --configuration=production --build-optimizer --stats-json --output-path=dist/en
  post_build:
    commands:
      #only run frontend update when the build is success
      - bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"
      - aws s3 rm s3://$S3_BUCKET --recursive
      #generating root language
      - aws s3 cp dist/en s3://$S3_BUCKET --recursive 
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
cache:
  paths:
    - '/root/.m2/**/*'
    - '/root/.npm/**/*'
    - 'build/**/*'
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe with CodeBuild the convention is to set the var when calling the project as I think each line is a separate shell. So for example with the buckets as parameters 'S3_BUCKET_DEV' & 'S3_BUCKET_PROD' in a cloudformation template:

```
          - Name: Dev
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Build
              Owner: AWS
              Provider: CodeBuild
              Version: "1"
            Configuration:
              ProjectName: !Ref DeployProj
              EnvironmentVariables: !Sub |
                [
                  {"name":"S3_BUCKET","value":"${S3_BUCKET_DEV}","type":"PLAINTEXT"}
                ]

            InputArtifacts:
              - Name: Whatever
            RunOrder: 2


          - Name: Prod
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Build
              Owner: AWS
              Provider: CodeBuild
              Version: "1"
            Configuration:
              ProjectName: !Ref DeployProj
              EnvironmentVariables: !Sub |
                [
                  {"name":"S3_BUCKET","value":"$S3_BUCKET_PROD","type":"PLAINTEXT"}
                ]

            InputArtifacts:
              - Name: Whatever
            RunOrder: 2
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I'm not familiarized with this kind of structure what you provided. I'm more working on YAML code. If I understood your code, you will run code build twice while the reqirement is to run it one time. Then make a check : if MANUAL_APPROVAL comes from user, then go to PROD

Comment: To try and clarify, you don't set the variable within buildspec, rather you pass the variable to codebuild when you execute the project within your pipeline. The variable belongs to the Stage/Action in the code pipeline definition. My example shows how to do this in Cloudformation. If you are not using Cloudformation, you can edit the pipeline definition in the console and set the variable there.